# Ruby on Rails string scan and regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to get image url "http://www.test.com/image.jpg" out from the string:

```
"&lt;img align=&quot;right&quot; alt=&quot;Title &quot; src=&quot;http://www.test.com/image.jpg&quot; width=&quot;120&quot; /&gt;&lt;"
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
module MyHelper

    def getMymage(allDesc)
        allDesc = "&lt;img align=&quot;right&quot; alt=&quot;Title &quot; src=&quot;http://www.test.com/image.jpg&quot; width=&quot;120&quot; /&gt;&lt;"
        allDesc = allDesc.scan(src=&quot;(\S+)&quot;)
    end
end
```

I got the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tAMPER
        allDesc = allDesc.scan(src=&quot;(\S+)&quot;)
                                    
syntax error, unexpected $undefined
        allDesc = allDesc.scan(src=&quot;(\S+)&quot;)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please correct the encoding of pasted text, it would be much easier to help you then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp is missing a start "/" and some extra stuff

```
allDesc.scan(/src=\&quot;([a-z0-9_.\-:\/]+)&quot;/i)
```

but you get an array as a response:

```
=> [["http://www.test.com/image.jpg"]]
```

I'd suggest using the matching operator and then use the first match variable:

```
allDesc =~ /(http:\/\/[a-z0-9_.-i\/]+)/ && $1
```

Comment: Thanks. almost there. Just a little bug. for image url like: http://www.test.com/images/1-2-3.jpg, it returns the url: http://www.test.com/images/1

Comment: I modified it a bit: allDesc =~ /(http:\/\/\S+)/ && $1 , but there is quotation at the end.

Comment: Just put a & outside your matching group like this allDesc =~ /(http:\/\/\S+)&/ && $1
 => "http://www.test.com/image.jpg"

Comment: allDesc =~ /(http:\/\/\S+)&/ && $1 doesn't return anything tho

Comment: does allDesc still contain the string? works for me: ree-1.8.7-2010.02 :043 > allDesc
 => "&lt;img align=&quot;right&quot; alt=&quot;Title &quot; src=&quot;http://www.test.com/image.jpg&quot; width=&quot;120&quot; /&gt;&lt;" 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 :044 > allDesc =~ /src=\&quot;([a-z0-9_.\-:\/]+)&quot;/i && $1
 => "http://www.test.com/image.jpg"

Comment: I want to ask, in the scan example, since only one pair of () for group capturing is used, why is it that the return result is an array of array?

Comment: If theres at least matchgroup .scan responds with array of array, if there's no matchgroup if returns an array of strings.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment on sunkencity's answer, but regex that solves the dash problem is:

```
/src=\&quot;([a-z0-9_.\-:\/]+)&quot;/i
```

Comment: i tried allDesc =~ /src=\&quot;([a-z0-9_.\-:\/]+)&quot;/i but it doesn't return anything?

Comment: even with this: allDesc =~ /src=\&quot;([a-z0-9_.\-:\/]+)&quot;/i && $1